# Stackable Panel Delphi Component

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-2010

does anyone know of a Delphi component that implements something similar to what jquery sortable does, but for a desktop application?

i.e. a vertical control that contains a number of panels that can be reordered and also used as containers for other components (specifically TMemos containing different bits of text).

Thanks for any info,

Breandan.

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using?  I'm asking because you may or may not have access to some built-in controls depending on your version.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. I'm using Delphi 2010 currently.

Comment: @Jerry, I think it would be best if you answer the question, and then mention in it that it only applies to some versions. That way, even if *this* user doesn't have the necessary version, *other* people wondering the same thing might still be able to benefit from this question.

Comment: Is TCategoryPanel in D2010?  I can't remember.

Answer (score 1):

While I do it from code, and not designtime, this is what I would use a TScrollbox or TPanel containing some Frames or Panels, which are all aligned top, for.  If I want a collapse/expand for the frames, I just put a button in the frame that allows you to collapse the frame to a minimal height such as 20 pixels when collapsed, and something taller when expanded.

the frames inside could really be any control you want, even Panels containing a few other controls. The top level controls can be reordered within the parent panel or scrollbox.

Answer (score 0):

TMS Has TAdvPanelGroup that can be collapsed/expanded.  See screenshot in the lower-right:
http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advpanel.asp

Answer (score 0):

Only one run, then I move and resize them from the running application.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here's the dfm:

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 337
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object clbr1: TCoolBar
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 635
    Height = 313
    Bands = <
      item
        Control = gb1
        ImageIndex = -1
        MinHeight = 123
        Width = 629
      end
      item
        Control = pnl1
        ImageIndex = -1
        MinHeight = 112
        Width = 629
      end>
    object gb1: TGroupBox
      Left = 11
      Top = 0
      Width = 620
      Height = 123
      Caption = 'gb1'
      TabOrder = 0
      object lbledt1: TLabeledEdit
        Left = 112
        Top = 40
        Width = 121
        Height = 21
        EditLabel.Width = 32
        EditLabel.Height = 13
        EditLabel.Caption = 'lbledt1'
        TabOrder = 0
      end
    end
    object pnl1: TPanel
      Left = 11
      Top = 125
      Width = 620
      Height = 112
      Caption = 'pnl1'
      TabOrder = 1
      object rg1: TRadioGroup
        Left = 128
        Top = 4
        Width = 185
        Height = 105
        Caption = 'rg1'
        Items.Strings = (
          'dsfsdf'
          'sdfsdfsd')
        TabOrder = 0
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't understand what we're looking at. Could you add some sentences explaining what your answer does? And could you clarify your first sentence? *What* does only one run, and why can't more run it?

Comment: With "One run", I wanna mean that I haven't modified the UI thru the designer... I have only drag & drop the "panel" when the application was launched. And the panels contains controls. So as I'm not sure to understand perfectly the question, I show what could be done just with the dfm displayed

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a standard control that does what you want in Delphi 2007, but I would offer a custom solution similar to the one Warren suggested.  The main difference is that I would create it within a TFrame so you could more easily maintain the code that allows you to manipulate the controls and their interaction with each other.  You could also create methods within the frame for adding new panels (with memos and the text to display), move them around, etc.

It's a bit of work but it can also be a great learning experience.  The best part is once you are done you can reuse that frame anywhere you want on any form or within another frame.  If you do it right it will work without hassle as well.